# Open Report based on text field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a form with a button and a text box as well as some other data. 
I need to open a report with calculated fields based on the value entered in the text box when the button is pressed. When a user enters a value into the text box it would open the report with only fields with that value.

Currently I am using

```
Private Sub Command11_Click()
DoCmd.OpenReport "Mileage", acViewPreview, , "Truck #" & Me.FrmTruck.Value & "'"
End Sub
```

This would work if it did not try to find a text box on the opened report named Truck #(EnteredValue) I am sure I am missing something since I have done this before but I can't place on how to filter based on the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Record Source of that report includes a field named *Truck #*, enclose that name in square brackets when you create the *WhereCondition* option for `OpenReport`, ie `[Truck #]`

Then, if the datatype of that field is numeric ...

```vb
DoCmd.OpenReport "Mileage", acViewPreview, , "[Truck #] = " & Me.FrmTruck.Value
```

Or if the datatype is text ...

```vb
DoCmd.OpenReport "Mileage", acViewPreview, , "[Truck #] = '" & Me.FrmTruck.Value & "'"
```

Note, if `Me.FrmTruck` is not the text box you mentioned where the user enters their search value, replace it with the correct text box name.